# Setting Glassfish 4 with jdbc automatically rather to work around manually

Tags: eclipse, maven, jdbc, glassfish

I got following local setting:

- Eclipse Kepler
- Maven 3
- Glassfish 4

I want to run JSF with MySql.JSF 2.0 works fine on the server.The problem I got is the connection to the database.
I did all settings at the admin of glassfish and here is the persistence.xml I got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="actors" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>jdbc/example</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
</properties>
```

Maven dependency for MySQL:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Get a jdbc not found exception...

The question is how can I setup Glassfish to use the maven dependency so that I don't need to integrate the jdbc.jar manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid according to the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#gkpci) you have to do it this way